# Levels of Independent Variables, or more Independent Variables ANOVA

Tags: anova, categorical-encoding

Participants are grouped into 'high stress', 'medium stress' and 'low stress' for a study on Cortisol levels. Does this mean there is one IV (stress level) with three levels (high, medium, low) or does high, medium and low mean there are thee different IVs?

Comment: The former i.e. 3 levels of 1 variable.

Comment: It often means *both*: conceptually, stress is a single "variable" but for computational and reporting purposes it is *encoded* as three distinct variables (one of which often is a "constant," "baseline," or "intercept" value).  See our threads on ["dummy encoding of categorical variables"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=dummy+coding+categorical).